# (Angular) How can I get the #tag definition in html to Javascript?

Tags: javascript, angular

I am having difficulty working on an Angular project.

In HTML...

```
<input #abc>...</input>
```

In Javascript

```
let var = ... *(how can i get the input element 'abc' to javascript?)*
```

I know it's too basic,
I am having a lot of trouble. Help!

Comment: `<input #abc>...</input>` is invalid markup

Comment: If I am not mistaken using #tag is not a valid construct in markup. This will lead to unpredictable behavior in browsers but in most of the case, your tag will not be rendered at all. So you can't access an element by it.

Comment: firstly check which type of forms you are using. There are 2 types of forms in angular2+ 1. [Template-driven forms](https://angular.io/guide/forms) 2. [Reactive forms](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this a template reference, you need to grab this element using `@ViewChild` decorator

```
@Component({
    template:" <input #abc>...</input> "
})
export class SomeComponent implements AfterViewInin{

    @ViewChild("abc")
    element:ElementRef<HtmlElement>;

    ngAfterViewInit(){
       console.log(this.element.nativeElement);
    }

}
```

I encourage you to read, the following topics to get the knowledge for that
https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-calls-an-viewchild for viewChild
https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#template-syntax for template reference

Answer (score 1):

you can refererence it with a 
`@VhiewChild('abc') myInput: ElementRef;`.
however if you want JUST value more valid and easy way to make a field on you class, lets say `value`
and update it when your input updates `<input (input)="value = $event.target.value" [value]="value">`

Answer (score 1):

if you use event

`<input #abc (click)="getabc(abc)">...</input>`

`getabc(element) { console.log(abc) } //element input`

if just get in .ts

`@ViewChild("abc") element:ElementRef<HtmlElement>;`

you can get `element` .